# Return another value when row is inexistent

Tags: sql, row, firebird

In a database table with a structure like this :

Table 1

```
Name | Id
 A     1
 B     2
```

Table 2

```
Table1's ID | IntValue
     1           11
     2           66
```

now, there is a query which joins the 2 tables and outputs something like

```
A | 11
B | 66
```

but the problem is that when, let's say row (A,1) gets deleted from table1 the query outputs

```
  | 11
B | 66
```

so instead of writing A it leaves it null because the row doesn't exist.

My question is: Instead of leaving it null, is there any option to make it write "Item Inexistent" or smth?

My database is Firebird 2.1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  COALESCE(t1.name, 'Item nonexistent'), t2.intValue
FROM    table2 t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        table1 t1
ON      t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answers are always working perfectly